# Mobilejquery calling the function 2 times, while click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i am making a Game Using mobilejquery in which i am calling a function using a link like this :

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
    var params = {
            honeyComb       : $('#honeyComb'),
            honeyCell       : $('#honeyComb span.box'),
            timeCountClock  : $('#honeyComb h2'),
            totalSeconds    : Number(10),
            popUp           : $('#how2Play'),
            popTrigger      : $('div.navi-right a.hp'),
            backScreen      : $('#backScreen')
        }


    $('a.play').click( function(){ honeyCellClicks(params);}) // starting from home page
    $('.playAgain').click(function(){ $("#how2Play,#backScreen").fadeOut(), alert("call from in")}) // restarting the game;

    alert('CALL from out')

});
```

while page loads, i am getting alert "call from out", and when i am going to next page using(a.play) click i am getting "call from out", later i am click on the "playAgain" it alerts 2 times('call from in')... what is the issue?

what i need is, while i click on the 'playAgain' it should call one time only.. how can i make like this or i made any mistrake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#YourPageID').live('pagecreate',function(event){
var params = {
            honeyComb       : $('#honeyComb'),
            honeyCell       : $('#honeyComb span.box'),
            timeCountClock  : $('#honeyComb h2'),
            totalSeconds    : Number(10),
            popUp           : $('#how2Play'),
            popTrigger      : $('div.navi-right a.hp'),
            backScreen      : $('#backScreen')
        }


    $('a.play').click( function(){ honeyCellClicks(params);}) // starting from home page
    $('.playAgain').click(function(){ $("#how2Play,#backScreen").fadeOut(), alert("call from in")}) // restarting the game;

    alert('CALL from out')
});
```

Try this and see.

Comment: yes, it works. what is the logic behind this, i unable to understan the event handlers with mobilejquery... thanks for you. in case if it's possible can you give me some advice on mobilejquery eventlisteners..?

Comment: Mobile jquery suggests not to use $(document).ready. instead you should use pageinit in new version. You can read more in the events. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html Ideally if you replace pagecreate with pageinit then it should work too. Try and see plz.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro in mobile jquery, but what about

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
```

There is probably more "init" call, so you add two event hanlers to the links, that's why it's called twice after click.